# If statement syntax eror

Tags: shell, if-statement, sh

I am trying to figure out how to check to see if the first input will end with `.txt`. It seems like the standard if statement syntax does not apply to my code based upon the way I am getting the input. Does anyone know the proper syntax for the else if statement in my first if statement in my code?

```
 #!/bin/sh

printf "%b %b\n" "$*"

if [ "$1" = "-help" ]
then
    echo "Cool Beans"
elif [ "$1" = "*.txt" ]
then
    echo "text recd"

else
    echo "first input not valid"
fi

if [ "$2" = "-help" ]
then
    echo "help options"
else
    echo "second input not valid"
fi
```

Comment: in bash you could certainly use regular expression matching ( eg [[ $1 =~ \.txt ]] ) or variable substitutions ( eg [[ ${1%*.} = txt ]] ). not sure if this applies for sh. almost certainly the * will be expanded if not single quoted...

Comment: @setempler thanks. Im actually gonna change the tag to sh. Didnt even think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for pattern matching to work, can use Bash double-bracketed conditionals (while removing the quotes, which disable the matching) :

```
elif [[ "$1" = *.txt ]]
```

You can also use regular expression matching :

```
elif [[ "$1" =~ [.]txt$ ]]
```

Note that you must escape the period (or put it in brackets like I did) to prevent its special meaning of "any character" to be disabled, as well as anchor the regex to the end with `$` so that you are sure you are matching the extension, not a sub-string inside the file name.

If you want something that is not bash-specific, you can try :

```
elif [ "${1##*.}" = txt ]
```

The `"${1##*.}"` expansion removes the longest string that starts from the beginning of the variable named 1 (could be any variable) and ends with a period, leaving the extension only.

Comment: Nice, however the tag is for `sh`, not `bash`

Comment: @clearlight  The last proposal should be POSIX-compliant unless I am mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `case` statement for POSIX-compatible pattern matching:

```
printf "%b %b\n" "$*"

case $1 in
  -help) echo "Cool Beans" ;;
  *.txt) echo "text recd" ;;
  *) echo "first input not valid"
esac

case $2 in
  -help) echo "help options" ;;
  *) echo "second input not valid" ;;
esac
```